# Netbeans fonts rendering

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, fonts

I usually use Eclipse, but I'd also like to use Netbeans sometimes, especially the Netbeans Platform which looks quite nice.

The only problem I have is that rendering fonts on Netbeans is crappy, without any nice hinting so it looks quite bad in comparison to font rendering on Eclipse. That looks bad especially on Ubuntu.

Do you know how to improve the font rendering on Netbeans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding the following options to your netbeans.conf:

```
-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -J-Dswing.aatext=true
```

Answer (score 0):

fonts are rendered well on v6.9.1 and v7.01, but badly in v7.1rc2.
This has been fixed in a nightly build (ie. NetBeans IDE Build 201112270601)

Or, you may try editing netbeans.conf, ie. add:

> -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -J-Dswing.aatext=false

in netbeans_default_options. The above will disable swing's font AA and enable System's font AA.

But the SystemAA may be worse. IMHO Vista's font AA is lacking compared to the font AA rendering system in v7.01